# Python Subprocess not starting but no errors either

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, popen

I'd like to have a script that creates 2 simultaniuosly running while loops. To achieve that  I am trying to open another script (to have multiple scripts running at the same time instead of having all the code in one).
Main script:

```
#!/bin/env python
import sys
import subprocess
print sys.path
process = subprocess.Popen('/home/pi/test2.py', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Second script:

```
#!/bin/env python
import sys
i=1
print sys.path
while i<50:
    print i
    i=i+1
```

The main script terminates without errors but it looks like the second doesn't even start. Why?

Comment: Why do you need two while loops that are running simultaneously? Please explain what you actual _goal_ is. Thanks!

Comment: I need to get measurement data from sensors (= the duration of an input signal) - this means the script just waits approximately 30ms for the input signal to stop. at the same time i have to output 1ms signals every 20ms to control a motor. - do you know  a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the output of `test2.py` then you shouldn't specify `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`. That collects the standard out and allows you to access it via `process` object.

Also, for what it's worth, `shell=True` isn't a good idea unless you're certain you need it.

It will then look like this

```
subprocess.Popen(['/home/pi/test2.py'])
```

Comment: process = subprocess.Popen('/home/pi/test2.py') like this? then i get the Error No such file or directory

Comment: @xHascox Does the file exist and is it executable/

Comment: i think so - im not used to linux and python that much - if I open it manualy and run it it works.

Comment: What does "If I open it manually" mean? Can you run `/home/pi/test2.py` from a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to sigmavirus24s answer. When you don't set `shell=True` you have to pass the arguments as a list like this `['/home/pi/test2.py']` and pass that as the first argument. For many arguments use the `shlex` modules `split` function that splits a `string` to a list of arguments for you.

Edit: For the script to work you need to pass `['python', '/home/pi/test2.py']` as the argument. This tells `python` to run the script.

Comment: subprocess.Popen(['/home/pi/test2.py']) results in Error 2 no such file or directory

Comment: Instead of `['/home/pi/test2.py']` use `['python', '/home/pi/test2.py']`. That works for me

Comment: I dont get any Errors even if the path i type is complete nonsense, but test2.py doesnt get started.

Comment: Well it worked on my RPi when I set `process = subprocess.Popen(['python',  '/home/pi/test2.py'] ) ` and ran the first file in bash. It printed the numbers from 1 to 49. Also since you are on Linux have you run `chmod +x` command on the test2.py so it can be executed.